# Converting a path to string returns unicode codec problem

Tags: python, c++

I am trying to use python function on c++, and my python function takes str as argument and returns float value. I want to run the function on every file on the specific path.

But `Py_BuildValue()` keeps returning `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x91 in position 1: invalid start byte`. How can I fix this?

Code is as follows:

<c++ code>

```
PyObject *pName, *pModule, *pFunc, *pValue, *pArg, *ptemp, *objectsRepresentation;
Py_Initialize();
pName = PyUnicode_FromString("my_module");
pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, "my_func");
std::string path = "my_dir_path";
for (const auto & entry : fs::directory_iterator(path))
{
    pArg = Py_BuildValue("s", entry.path().string());
    pValue = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArg);
    double result = PyFloat_AsDouble(pValue);
    cout << result << endl;
}
Py_Finalize();
```

<my_module.py>

```
def my_func(file_path: str) -> float:
    tm = cv2.Tickmeter()
    tm.start()
    run_something()
    tm.stop()
    return tm.getTimeMilli()
```

Comment: Use a debugger and step through the code to see what values are assigned to `entry`. Maybe the problem comes from `..` and `.` directories.

Comment: @IvanVenkov for it is using `directory_iterator`, obviously `std::filesystem::directory_entry` is assigned, and `.string()` converts it to path string, and then every entry make errors with unicode codec error. `.u8string()` doesn't help either. Folder path is fine and I can see files assigned well.

Comment: The `"s"` expects a "C string", not a `std::string`.  Try `entry.path().string().c_str()`. (You can't use C++ objects with the Python API.) And don't ignore [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/arg.html#c.Py_BuildValue).

Comment: @molbdnilo do you know of an existing duplicate question for the problem?

Comment: @molbdnilo Thanks! It solved my problem. For I am not used to C++, I didn't have idea about types either... Thanks again!